# concealing the start and end pattern in syntax region

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to learn multi line highlighting and have managed to get the following working

```
syntax region myMinusStart start=/^\s\+zzzz / end=/^\s\+qqqq / concealends
```

But the concealends is not hiding the line with  `zzzz $` or the line with `qqqq $`

Reading `:h :syn-concealends' it seemed to say that to conceal the ends they need a match group so I tried

```
syntax match myMinusBegin /^\s\+zzzz / contained conceal
syntax match myMinusEnd  /^\s\+qqqq /  contained conceal
```

[image: example]

But the start line still didn't conceal. Any suggestions?

Update: For some reason the `zzzz`  is reporting as MyMinusStart which would suggest why it's not concealing.

I also tried the following thinking the pattern had to differ but with no luck

```
syntax match myMinusBegin /^\s\+zzzz / contained conceal
syntax match myMinusEnd  /^\s\+qqqq /  contained conceal
```

**Update**
I tried Karl's suggestion, below, and that hid the start and end markers but after removing transparent, as it hid the color highlighting , there's a termination problem in the pattern I can't work out

**Karl's suggestion**
    syntax region myMinusStart start=/^\s+zzzz / end=/^\s+qqqq /
        \ transparent
        \ contains=myMinusBegin,myMinusEnd

```
syntax match myMinusBegin /^\s\+zzzz / contained conceal
syntax match myMinusEnd  /^\s\+qqqq /  contained conceal
```

[image: Example 1]

For some reason once I enter `zzzz $` and `qqqq $` once it color hilights to the end of the file. There are three blocks that match the region but I can't see why the coloring continues until file end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
syntax region myMinusStart start=/^\s\+zzzz / end=/^\s\+qqqq /
      \ keepend
      \ contains=myMinusBegin,myMinusEnd

syntax match myMinusBegin /^\s\+zzzz / contained conceal
syntax match myMinusEnd  /^\s\+qqqq /  contained conceal
```

Note that you need to set `conceallevel` e.g. to 2, see `:h conceallevel`.

**Update**: A simpler alternative:

```
syntax region myMinusRegion matchgroup=myMinusDelim
      \ start=/^\s\+zzzz / end=/^\s\+qqqq /
      \ concealends
```

Of course, if you want the start and end matches to be highlighted differently, then the original version is necessary.

Comment: Karl thanks. That almost worked , removing the transparent as that removed the coloring, but there's a pattern end problem. See update

Comment: try to add the option `keepends` to the `syntax region` command.

Comment: Do you mean `keepend` not `keepends`?

Comment: Yes @Jan, you're right. I've also updated to add a better version.